# 6 rings with equidistant intersection points

Tags: geometry, spheres

I should note, before I begin, I'm a programmer, not a mathematician, so if my question seems stupid, there's a reason for that. :-j

I'm trying to create a 3d model of a sphere with 6 rings around it. Where the rings intersect are important; they need to be equidistant from one another, and there can't be any more than 2 rings intersecting at any point. This is for a game, where the points of intersection are areas of maximum flexibility.

As a degenerate case, consider the case for 3 rings;

http://s15.postimg.org/e5k18koyj/ring_problem.png

As the image shows, each point where 2 rings intersect has at least 90 degrees of arc between itself and any other point of intersection. What I want is a model with 6 rings, where the distance between any arbitrary point of intersection and it's closest neighbor is maximized.

Here's the openSCAD code I used to create this image. I expect people on this forum will mostly be interested in the rotation matrix I'm using.

```
orbit_ring_rotations = [
    [[    0,   0,   0]],
    [[    0,  90,   0]],
    [[    0,  90,  90]]
];
    for (i = [0:1:3 -1])
        rotate(orbit_ring_rotations[i][0])
            rotate_extrude(angle = 360, $fn=quality)
                translate([3, 0, 0])
                    circle(r = .1);
```

I really don't have any idea how to attack this problem from here, except to write a program that tries all of the combinations (for integer values between 0 and 359 in the rotation matrix, anyway). But seeing as that's kinda complicated, if there's a math-y solution, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Icosidodecahedron* may be a suitable choice. Each face is either a regular pentagon or equilateral triangle with total spherical symmetry. The model can be made out either of six rings or six ( 10 sided) polygons.It was possible to make a model using discarded Venetian blind strips. All rings are great circles. You can google other sites as well where rings were assembled.

EDIT1:

I found the symmetric assembly of six great circles so pleasing.. to 3d print an icosidodecahedron later.

[IcosidodecaHedron](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ir0KwthTuzE)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron

Answer (score 1):

It depend's on whether the rings are restricted as great circles.

Analogous to [Thomson Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem) distributing charges on a sphere.  Say you have one ring at the equator, there're 5 rings left.  It's most likely have 5 meridian rings.  But there'll be two kinds of distances of intersections.

If **not**, try the rings on every faces of a cube.

Comment: +1 If the OP needs great circles and equidistant intersections, 2 rings at a time, I'm fairly sure this will be impossible. Their example with 3 rings configured like an octahedron's edges is nice, but a fluke.

Comment: Interesting. Taking a look at this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem#Known_solutions

The several of the known solutions are just polyhedra. So they'll be an intersection at each vertex of an X vertex polyhedra, where X is the number of intersections (for 6 rings, X = 30).